# Como inserir uma imagem no meu doc html para que sirva como imagem de fundo(background)

Tags: html, css

Cumprimentos. Gostaria de saber como inserir uma imagem em meu documento html para que a mesma sirva como background no meu site. A imagem encontra_se no desktop do meu PC com o nome "backg.jpg". Agradecia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize **CSS** para atingir o resultado pertendido `background-image: url(CAMINHO_DA_IMAGEM)`.

Encontre em baixo um exemplo de como utilizar **CSS** para inserir uma imagem de fundo em toda a pagina.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Teste de imagem de fundo</title>
   <style>
          body{
             background-image: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Alien_Ink_2560X1600_Abstract_Background_dh8LV2F.jpg); /*caso a sua imagem de fundo se encontre no mesmo diretorio use apenas background-image:url(backg.jpg) */
             background-size: cover; /*caso nao pertenda utilizar htm5 substitua 'cover' por 100%*/
             background-repeat: no-repeat; /*previne que a imagem se repita ao longo da pagina*/
          }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Considere utilizar um servidor virtual, por exemplo **[XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html)** para criar seus projetos em um ambiente +/- parecido com um servidor web real.

Evite criar projetos diretamente do seu Ambiente de Trabalho (Desktop).

Answer (score 0):

css

```
   body
    {
         background-image: url("caminho_da_imagem.extensao");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando eu comecei tinha dificuldade para entender como referenciar imagens e arquivos, se você esta usando windows e a imagem esta na área de trabalho você vai fazer mais ou menos isso, `c:\usuarios\seu-usuario\desktop\nome-imagem.jpg` não faça isso!

Eu aconselho utilizar a imagem na mesma pasta do index.html, você pode fazer a seguinte estrutura:

- nome-pasta-projeto/

  - index.html
  - estilo.css
  - img/

    - bg.jpg

E no css fazer o seguinte:

```
body
{
     background-image: url("img/bg.jpg");
}
```

Como pode ver no css nós chamamos o `bg.jpg` dentro da pasta `img`

Observe sempre aonde estão seus arquivos e terá muito menos confusão.